# Integrating google code SVN repository with MantisBT

Tags: svn, integration, google-code, mantis

I am trying to figure out how to integrate my google code repository with my mantis bug tracking system.  I know google allows you to use post-commit web hooks, but I can't figure out what the exact URL should be.  There is a lot of information about how to integrate the two, but they all require calling the mantis script from the shell, but I don't have shell access to my web server. Is there any way to get this integration set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case you're still working on it, I modified the "shell script" to run with the GC post-commit hook. You can find it there : http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=12569

Answer (score 0):

You want [this blog post](http://alt-tag.com/blog/archives/2006/11/integrating-mantis-and-subversion/). You'll need curl on the server to send commands to mantis, which might be a problem, depending on the scripting language you use to write the hook.

The integration works very well, though I couldn't tie the subversion user who commits to the mantis user who closes the bug. In the end, I just used a 'svn' user who did all the mantis manipulation and added the svn author property to the log message. I also added a list of folders changed (not files, sometimes the changeset list was too big for my purposes) to the log message - that proved to be very useful later on.